# how to get value by jQuery+Codeigniter and show in input field?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I got some problem about receive value from server , and show the value in input .

Sometimes, if I want to show the value in page, I will use the POST method, then set the input'ID in controller and model, and use `foreach()` in page you want to show , therefore the work is done.

But, if I want to show the value in input'field, how I need to do for it ?

I write some code for this and try to use AJAX receive and show in input, it's not working,can everybody help me to solve this problem , please....... Σ( ￣□￣；)

I try to create a new model and a new page for it, there is a very simple form, the code is below:

**view:kungfu.php**

```
<div style="width:250px;float:left;">
<form id="pr_form" action="<?php echo site_url();?>/static_data/kungfu_act" method="post">

NUM：<input id="num" name="num" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
NAME：<input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
LOCAL：<input id="local" name="local" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
KUNGFU：<input id="kungfu" name="kungfu" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
<span id="loading" style="display:none">Loading!!</span><br>
<span id="complete" style="display:none">Complete!!</span>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;height:50px;padding-top:10px">
<input id="query" name="query" class="btn" type="button" value="QUERY">
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

**model:pr_model.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
class Pr_model extends CI_Model {  

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function pr_query()
    {

        $query=$this->db->get("kungfu_table"); 
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**controller:static_data.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Static_data extends CI_Controller {

    public function kungfu()
    {
        $this->load->view('kungfu');
    }

    public function kungfu_query()
    {
        $this->load->model("pr_model");
        $data = array(
            "kungfu" =>$this->pr_model->pr_query()
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

if I want to show the value in normal page , I will use `foreach()` but I don't know how to show in input, I try to use `getjson()` , but no working . can somebody teach me ?

**// 2013/11/30 re-edit**

**dear Suleman:**

I try to write some code about .ajax() , but I still got problem , the other section was the same , but the controller had be change :

**controller:static_data.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Static_data extends CI_Controller {

    public function kungfu()
    {
        $this->load->view('kungfu');
    }

    public function kungfu_maxquery()
    {
        $this->load->model("pr_model");
        $data = $this->pr_model->pr_maxquery();

        $max=json_encode($data);
        echo $max;


    }
}
```

**model:pr_model.php**

```
function pr_maxquery()
    {
        $this->db->select_max("num");
        $maxquery=$this->db->get("kungfu_table");
        return $maxquery->result();
    }
```

and I try to edit a js file for `.ajax()`,but the Chrome console tell me "Uncaught ReferenceError: maxnum is not defined " , can you tell me how to edit it ?

```
$("#newone").click(function(){
        $("#num").val(function(){
            max_response = $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>/static_data/kungfu_maxquery",
                cache:false,
                data: "num:"+maxnum
            });
            max_response.done(function(){                
                return maxnum;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Would you print data in "view:kungfu.php" file, and append the output in your question?

Comment: Is your model data available in "view"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `model` data is available in `view`, If available then need to alter your `inpup` fields:

```
NUM：<input id="num" value="<?php echo $data_for_first_input_filed; ?>" name="num" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
NAME：<input id="name" value="<?php echo $data_for_second_input_filed; ?>"  name="name" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
LOCAL：<input id="local" value="<?php echo $data_for_third_input_filed; ?>"  name="local" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
KUNGFU：<input id="kungfu" value="<?php echo $data_for_forth_input_filed; ?>"  name="kungfu" type="text" class="field_set"><br>
```

If you want to append data through `AJAX`, then here is sample code:

```
$("#newone").click(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/static_data/kungfu_maxquery",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'num':maxnum
    },
    cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $("#num").val(data['filed_name_returned']);
       $("#name").val(data['filed_name_returned']);
       $("#local").val(data['filed_name_returned']);
       $("#kungfu").val(data['filed_name_returned']);
    }
});
});
```

`AJAX` request is not a cheap call, we can get all the data in one request and can set that available data in success function. I do't know your table structure that' why I have appended one line extra `console.log(data);` that will show your returned data in console.

Comment: sure ... this is a very correct answer, but can you still teach me about "how to show this by jQuery ajax()" ??

Comment: Add console.log([returning data which you want to display in input fileds]) in your ajax success function. and append your printed data in your question.

Comment: thank you for your answer , I re-edit this question,please help me to solve it , thank you very much :)

Comment: please append the result in your question, when you hit the ajax request.